# elastic search results are not matching with search key

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am have done indexing the name. And it holds data like chair,chairs etc.

when I trying to search with "cha" it is not returning any chair or chairs.It is returning "shag rugs" where I am expecting the documents which has chair.

below is my code:

```
BoolQueryBuilder rootBoolQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();
MultiMatchQueryBuilder multiMatchQueryBuilder = multiMatchQuery(searchKey).field(
    SEARCH_CATEGORY_NAME_FIELD);
multiMatchQueryBuilder.fuzziness(Fuzziness.TWO);
multiMatchQueryBuilder.type(Type.BEST_FIELDS);
rootBoolQuery.must(multiMatchQueryBuilder);
```

search request:

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"multi_match":{"query":"cha","fields":["categoryname^1.0"],"type":"best_fields","operator":"OR","slop":0,"fuzziness":"2","prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":50,"zero_terms_query":"NONE","auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"boost":1.0}}],"adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":1.0}},"sort":[{"productcount":{"order":"desc"}}]}
```

search Response:

```
{
"took": 4,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": {
        "value": 1,
        "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "category",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "331869",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
                "rootcategory": "Home",
                "categorycode": "Shag_Rugs",
                "categoryname": "        Shag Rugs",
                "categoryid": 331869,
                "parentcategory": "    Rugs",
                "productcount": 59
            },
            "sort": [
                59
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Mapping:

```
"categoryname": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            }
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: What is the mapping for `name`? It looks fuzziness is causing the issue

Comment: added in the description

Comment: Your search query contains fuzzy parameter. Remove it and you will get matching results. Do you have that for a purpose?

Comment: if I remove Fuzzy zero results are coming up

Comment: Is that solved your problem?

Comment: no results should comeup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219240/discussion-between-gibbs-and-sree).

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use **Prefix Query** for your use case and let me know whether it solved your purpose or not. Please go [Click here to get more info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html)

Comment: I need to get the document which are matching with any part.Not only at the start